# Is this theory as strong as ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, foundations, alternative-set-theories

Let $T$ be a theory with a binary relation $\in$, a constant $U$, and the following axioms:
\begin{align}
\text{axiom of transitivity} &\quad \forall x \forall y (x \in y \in U \rightarrow x \in U) \\
\text{axiom of supertransitivity} &\quad \forall x \forall y (x \subseteq y \in U \rightarrow x \in U) \\
\text{axiom schema of comprehension} &\quad \forall \bar{a}_{\in U}(\forall x (\phi(x, \bar{a}) \rightarrow x \in U) \rightarrow \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi(x, \bar{a})))
\end{align}
where $\phi$ does not contain $U$ and $\bar{a}$ denotes a sequence of parameters. Then $T$ proves
\begin{align}
\text{empty set} &\quad \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \not\in y) \\
\text{powerset} &\quad \forall a_{\in U} \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x \subseteq a) \\
\text{union} &\quad \forall a_{\in U} \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \exists z (x \in z \in a)) \\
\text{specification} &\quad \forall a_{\in U} \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi \land x \in a) \\
\text{pairing} &\quad \forall a_{\in U} \forall b_{\in U} \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow x = a \lor x = b) \\
\text{infinity} &\quad \exists y_{\in U} (\varnothing \in y \land \forall x_{\in y} (x \cup \{x\} \in y))
\end{align}
Does this theory [interpret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretability) ZFC? Proving a form of [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Collection) or replacement, as [Reinhardt did](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484370900112) for [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory), seems [sufficient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48365/minimal-subset-of-axioms-for-zfc/54328?noredirect=1#comment892440_54328).

Comment: Do you want to add extensionality?

Comment: @NoahSchweber My understanding is that [extensionality is not necessary](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168287/is-there-any-research-on-set-theory-without-extensionality-axiom/168307#168307).

Comment: If you have appropriate replacement in the larger theory ... which isn't obvious here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hence the question :)

Comment: Then I'd explicitly mention that you care about avoiding extensionality here, because even including it the question seems interesting.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'd rather know the answer for the question **with** extensionality, since I think even that should be no stronger than ZC plus countable replacement. =)

Comment: @user21820 Feel free to assume extensionality if it allows you to prove something interesting about the power of this theory that doesn't seem provable without it.

Comment: @user76284: Sure, though my main reason for favouring the question with extensionality is that it is an innocuous axiom.

Answer (score 5):

I've asked before if class construction of Ackermann's is really needed for its equi-interpretability with ZFC [see [here]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325854/is-ackermanns-set-theory-minus-class-comprehension-equal-to-zf) But here your question dropped Extensionality, and it also has a problem with its formulation, although I think that was intended and not a typo, that is the parameters of $\phi$ in 
comprehension are *unrestricted* in $U$, but this would render the theory inconsistent! Take the formula $x \in A \land x \notin x$, now substitute that formula in comprehension, since $A$ can be any class, substitute it by $U$, then $y$ would be the Russell set.

So you must add the restriction that all parameters of $\phi$ must be bounded in $U$. Now if that's done, then you'll get a fragment of Ackermann's set theory, which is of course consistent relative to Ackermann's. Now in this fragment it is a theorem that for every element $x$ of $U$ all of co-extensionals of $x$ are also elements of $U$ and also proves the existence of a set of all of those that is an element of $U$, and I think this would be enough to interpret Extensionality (that if class construction schema of Ackermann's set theory is not needed for the equi-interpretability of ZFC with Ackermann's). But as its stands for now, your theory is inconsistent.

Comment: Good catch. I clarified that the parameters should be in $U$.

Comment: @user76284, then I'd think the whole matter depends on the answer presented in the linked question. If it is correct, which I think so, then this theory would interpret ZFC. Since we can get the set of all co-extensional sets to a set. However I didn't work out the details.

Comment: How does $(x \in A \land x \not\in x) \to x \in U$, which is required by the comprehension schema?

Comment: @user76284, comprehension has been changed *after* this answer, the older version reads: $$\begin{align}
 &\qquad \forall x (\phi \rightarrow x \in U) \rightarrow \exists y_{\in U} \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi)
\end{align}$$. Now for this version take $\phi$ to be $(x \in A \land x \not \in x)$, and take $A=U$ (since there is no restriction on what $A$ can be), then we'd have $ (x \in A \land x \not \in x) \to x \in U$, and so we fulfilled the antecedent of comprehension, but this leads to the Russell's paradox.

Answer (score 1):

We can build the cumulative hierarchy up to $V_{<ω^ω}$, if we have extensionality. Even without extensionality, we still can get to the same height but I do not know how to prove a linear hierarchy. I will use the term "set" synonymously with "member of $U$".

~ ~ ~

Let $C(A,S) ≡ A∈S ∧ ∀x{∈}S\ ∃y{∈}S\ ∀t\ ( t∈y ⇔ ∀z{∈}t\ ( z∈x ) )$.
[$C(A,S)$ says that $S$ includes $A$ and is closed under powerclass.]

Let $I(A,T) ≡ ∀x\ ( x∈T ⇔ ∀S\ ( C(A,S) ⇒ x∈S ) )$.
[$I(A,T)$ says that $T$ is the intersection of all $S$ satisfying $C(A,S)$.]

Then $∀A{∈}U\ ( C(A,U) )$ [by powerset] and hence $∀A{∈}U\ ∀x\ ( ∀S\ ( C(A,S) ⇒ x∈S ) ⇒ x∈U )$.

Thus $∀A{∈}U\ ∃B{∈}U\ ( I(A,B) )$ [by comprehension].

Thus $∀A{∈}U\ ∃!B{∈}U\ ( I(A,B) )$ [by extensionality].
[This will not be used later, but I included it to show what extensionality gains.]

~ ~ ~

We have reached $V_ω$ because $∃B{∈}U\ ( I(\varnothing,B) )$. In general, we can construct the set of finite powersets of any given set. We can capture this process and iterate it internally as follows.

~ ~ ~

Let $C'(A,S) ≡ A∈S ∧ ∀x{∈}S\ ∃y{∈}S\ ( I(x,y) )$.
[$C'(A,S)$ says that $S$ includes $A$ and is closed under $I$.]

Let $I'(A,T) ≡ ∀x\ ( x∈T ⇔ ∀S\ ( C'(A,S) ⇒ x∈S ) )$.
[$I'(A,T)$ says that $T$ is the intersection of all $S$ satisfying $C'(A,S)$.]

Then $∀A{∈}U\ ( C'(A,U) )$ [by above] and hence $∀A{∈}U\ ∀x\ ( ∀S\ ( C'(A,S) ⇒ x∈S ) ⇒ x∈U )$.

Thus $∀A{∈}U\ ∃B{∈}U\ ( I'(A,B) )$ [by comprehension].

~ ~ ~

We now have essentially reached $V_{ω·ω}$, because we essentially have $I(V_0,V_ω)$ and $I(V_ω,V_{ω·2})$ and in general $I(V_{ω·k},V_{ω·(k+1)})$ for any $k∈ω$. I say "essentially" since without extensionality it seems impossible to define $V_{ω·k}$ even though there is some $B$ satisfying $I'(\varnothing,B)$ and so this $B$ includes all the sets that are candidates for being $V_{ω·k}$.

We can clearly repeat this any finite number of times. The first time gave closure of levels (of the hierarchy) under ${}+1$. The second gave closure under ${}+ω$. The third gives closure under ${}+ω·ω$. The $n$-th gives closure under ${}+ω^n$.

Iterating this (externally) all the way gives $V_{<ω^ω}$. I do not see how to construct anything like $V_{ω^ω}$, even with extensionality, so this theory seems weaker than Z plus countable replacement. I would be very intrigued if someone goes beyond that. My intuition is not that good, but it feels like this theory is as strong as Z plus inductive construction (IC), where IC is the schema:

> $∀A\ ∃S{⊇}A\ ( ∀x{∈}S\ ( f(x)∈S ) ∧ ∀T{⊇}A\ ( ∀x{∈}T\ ( f(x)∈T ) ⇒ S⊆T ) )$, for every definable function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the answers given above! So I'll pose this answer as a partial answer to show that such approaches are invalid here.

I'll assume Extensionality throughout.

This theory proves that for any ordinal $\alpha \in U$, i.e. any set ordinal, the stage $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy is a set!

The reason is because this theory proves [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) scheme over set ordinals for properties definable after formulae eligible in comprehension.

Let take the property: $\exists x: x = P^\alpha(\emptyset)$ which is exactly $\exists x: x=V_\alpha$, now this doesn't use $U$ in it, and when $\alpha \in U$ then it qualifies for comprehension.

Now clearly for any limit set ordinal $\alpha$ if for every $\beta \in \alpha$ we have $\exists x \in U: x=V_\beta$, then by comprehension schema there exists a union of all $V_\beta$ stages! But this is $V_\alpha$, if $\alpha$ was a successor, then clearly $V_\alpha$ is the power set of $\bigcup V_{\beta < \alpha}$.

So by transfinite induction for any set ordinal $\alpha$, there exists $V_\alpha$.

Now to see that every $V_\alpha$ must be a set, is clear, since either $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, and since it is a set, then we can use the formula $ x \in V_{\beta \in \alpha}$ and by comprehension $V_\alpha$ would be a set. If $\alpha$ was a successor, then clearly $V_\alpha$ is the power set of the union of the prior stages, and since that union is a set, then it must be a set.

Therefor this theory proves: that for every ordinal $\alpha$:  $$\alpha \in U  \to V_\alpha \in U$$. Now this theory clearly proves infinity, and power, so it proves existence of all countable ordinals, and of course existence of uncountable ones as well.

Since this theory proves $\omega ^ \omega \in U$, then of course it proves that $V_{\omega^\omega}$ is a set.

Now to see how $\omega^\omega$ is a set, we need to define recursive tiers of succession:

Define $S_i$ as

$S_1(\alpha) = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$

$S_{i+1} (\alpha) = \bigcup (\bigcap x :\alpha \in x \land x \text{ closed under } S_i)$

Now each $S_i(\omega)=\omega^{i-1}$ when $i \geq 3$.

Now this theory proves that: for every natural number $n$: $$S_n(\omega) \in U \to S_{n+1} (\omega) \in U$$, so we simply construct the *set* $K=\{S_3(\omega), S_4 (\omega),...\}$, this is simply the intersection of all classes I such that: $$S_3(\omega) \in I \land \forall n (S_n(\omega) \in I \to S_{n+1}(\omega) \in I)$$; then $\omega^\omega = \bigcup K$.

Comment: Thanks. What does $x = \mathcal{P}^\alpha(\varnothing)$ mean, internally speaking? I assume the intended meaning is $\mathcal{P}$ applied $\alpha$ times to $\varnothing$, but what's the corresponding first-order formula in the language of the theory?

Comment: @user76284, a rather long formula, it means there exists a function $f$ (i.e. a class of ordered pairs that fulfills the criteria of being a function) whose domain is the ordinal $\alpha$ such that for any $\beta,\beta+1 \in \alpha [f(\beta+1)=P(f(\beta))]$ and any limit $\beta \in \alpha (f(\beta)=\bigcup f(\gamma)( \gamma <\beta))$ and $x = \bigcup rng(f)$ and $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.

Comment: Does this shorter statement suffice? $y = P^a(\varnothing)$ iff there exists a function $f$ such that
$$\forall b \left(b \in \operatorname{dom} f \rightarrow f(b) = \bigcup_{c \in b} P(f(c))\right)$$
and $f[a] = y$ (that is, the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) of $a$ under $f$ is $y$). Maybe this can be shorted further.

Comment: @user76284 sometimes this notation might be confusing, for example $\bigcup \phi(c)$ here would stand for $\{x \in y| \phi(y)\}$, which might be confused with $\bigcup (x)$ which means the set of all members of members of $x$.  You'll see this confusion for example when $b=\{\emptyset\}$. I'd prefer:  $$ \forall b \left(b \in \operatorname{dom} f \rightarrow f(b) = \{x \in P(f(c)): c \in b \}\right) $$

Comment: @user76284, and it should be $f(a)=y$ and not $f[a]=y$, for instance take $a=\omega$, we have $y=f[\omega]=\{\emptyset, P(\emptyset), PP(\emptyset),...\}$, while $y=f(\omega) = \bigcup(f[\omega])$ which is what we want! Take $a= 3 = \{0,1,2\}$ here $f[3]=\{0,P(0), PP(0)\}$ which is not $PPP(0)$. While $f(3)=PPP(0)$.

Comment: @user76284, I admit that I myself made an error in my own characterization (the first one above your response), I think we need to set $f(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to the question, but some thoughts:

For any relation $R$, say
\begin{align}
\text{$S$ is $R$-closed} \longleftrightarrow \forall x_{\in S} \exists y_{\in S} R(x,y)
\end{align}

Define the following relations:
\begin{align}
F(a, b) &\longleftrightarrow \forall x (x \in b \leftrightarrow x \in a \lor x \subseteq a) \\
F^\omega(a, b) &\longleftrightarrow \text{$b$ is the minimal $F$-closed set containing $a$} \\
F^{\omega \cdot \omega}(a, b) &\longleftrightarrow \text{$b$ is the minimal $F^\omega$-closed set containing $a$} \\
F^{\omega \cdot \omega \cdot \omega}(a, b) &\longleftrightarrow \text{$b$ is the minimal $F^{\omega \cdot \omega}$-closed set containing $a$} \\
& \dots \\
F^{\omega^{n+1}}(a, b) &\longleftrightarrow \text{$b$ is the minimal $F^{\omega^n}$-closed set containing $a$}
\end{align}

This can be interpreted as $b$ containing $a$ and being closed under transfinitely-long chains of $F$. Then
\begin{align}
    &\exists x F(\varnothing, x) && (V_1) \\
    &\exists x F^\omega(\varnothing, x) && (V_\omega) \\
    &\exists x F^{\omega \cdot \omega}(\varnothing, x) && (V_{\omega \cdot \omega}) \\
    & \dots \\
    &\exists x F^{\omega^n}(\varnothing, x) && (V_{\omega^n})
\end{align}

Thus it looks like we have at least $V_{< \omega^\omega}$, as the other answer pointed out.

---

More concisely, we can do the following for the ordinals: For notational convenience, assume extensionality. For a functional relation $f$, say
\begin{align}
\text{$x$ is $f$-closed} \leftrightarrow \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow f(y) \in x)
\end{align}
Let
\begin{align}
s(x) &= x \cup \{x\} \\
s^{\omega^{n+1}}(x) &= \text{intersection of all $s^{\omega^n}$-closed classes containing $x$}
\end{align}
These can be viewed as transfinite compositions of $s$. Then
\begin{align}
\varnothing \neq s^{\omega^n}(\varnothing) \in U
\end{align}